# Allow access of SharePoint files to everyone

Tags: sharepoint-online, php

I am working with PHP-SharePoint integration. I want to fetch files and show videos to all the users. I am partially successful but the problem is that it shows the videos only when I am logged in. When I logged out it stops showing videos. The reason is that I embed the path of video into HTML video tag and it shows only when it has access to that URL. So my question is that

*Is this possible to allow access of my SharePoint videos to everyone*?

Answer (score 1):

check your permission on this sites where this page avillable. If not success then create a new group and add other users on this group or share this site with your users.

Comment: No, I want to give access to general public

Comment: check your current permissions policy and let me know then I'll suggest you.

Comment: It says that you can't give access to people other than your organization